# Notify errors of my applications in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have check my Android developer [console](https://market.android.com/publish/Home) and notice that my application has 1 error report. Is there any way to config some alert, as an email, to inform you about this error, also new purchases, etc? If not I wont know that the application has failed until I check my android market account, isnt it?

Comment: I don't know if you can get alerts for errors in your current application, but if you use the [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) library you can get error reports automatically by mail or collect all reports in a Google document and let Google alert you when there is a new error report.